# How to get common values of an array between many document with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given these documents:

```
{
    values: [
        { attribute: 1 },
        { attribute: 2 },
        { attribute: 3 },
        { attribute: 4 },
    ]
},
{
    values: [
        { attribute: 2 },
        { attribute: 3 },
        { attribute: 4 },
    ]
},
{
    values: [
        { attribute: 2 },
        { attribute: 3 },
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the common "attribute" values:

```
[ 2, 3 ]
```

I'm looking at the aggregator framework, but I've found nothing that could really answer my need for now.

I'm using Mongo 2.4.6.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

**EDIT**

In fact, my documents can have duplicated attributes (but I want to count them only once per document).

Given this data

```
{
    values: [
        { attribute: 1 },
        { attribute: 2 },
        { attribute: 3 },
        { attribute: 3 },
        { attribute: 4 },
    ]
},
{
    values: [
        { attribute: 2 },
        { attribute: 2 },
        { attribute: 3 },
        { attribute: 4 },
    ]
},
{
    values: [
        { attribute: 2 },
        { attribute: 3 },
    ]
}
```

Then the query should return:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "values" : 2
                },
                {
                        "values" : 3
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Anand, the query you posted will count attribute "2" 4 times, instead of 3 times.
I tried to modify it, but this is still quite cryptic to me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you mean my "common" attribute values?  Do you want find attributes that are present in every document in the collection?  for example, 4 is present in the 1st and 2nd document. is that considered common?

Comment: Hello Anand. No I mean attribute must be present in all the documents. So, in this example only the attributes 2 and 3 must be selected.

Comment: I've posted a solution.  Check if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain if I understand your question completely, but I'm going to give a shot at it.

If you want to find only the attributes that are present in every document in the collection, one approach is to **get the document count in a separate query** and then use an aggregation query like below.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Unwind the values array
    { "$unwind" : "$values"}, 
    // Group by "values.attribute" and get the count for each
    { "$group" : {_id:"$values.attribute", count:{$sum:1}}}, 
    // Filter only those documents where count equals number of docs in the collection (i.e., 3)
    { "$match" : {count:3}}, // Replace 3 with document count
    // Project phase to make the result prettier and in the format you want
    { "$project" :{_id:0, values:"$_id"}}
])
```

This is the output you'll get when you run the above query:

```js
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "values" : 3
                },
                {
                        "values" : 2
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I don't think this can be achieved in a single query though (i.e., without running a separate query for the document count).  May be someone will post here if there's a better approach.

**EDIT:** For the edge case you have described, you can take advantage of the `_id` field that's present in every document and is unique across the collection by adding an additional $group phase including the `_id`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Unwind the values array
    { "$unwind" : "$values"}, 
    // Group by "_id" and "values.attribute" to pick just one element from the array per document
    { "$group" : {_id:{_id:"$_id", attrValue: "$values.attribute"}}},
    // Group by "values.attribute" and get the count for each
    { "$group" : {_id:"$_id.attrValue", count:{$sum:1}}}, 
    // Filter only those documents where count equals number of docs in the collection (i.e., 3)
    { "$match" : {count:3}}, // Replace 3 with document count
    // Project phase to make the result prettier and in the format you want
    { "$project" :{_id:0, values:"$_id"}}
])
```

Comment: Hello Anand. Thank you very much for your answer! It answers my need, but I've forgotten about a edge case that'll change slitghly the request. I've updated the initial question to show it to you. Regards.

Comment: I have added another query for the edge base.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

We've came up with this solution:

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    { $project: { "values.attribute": 1} },
    { $unwind: "$values" },
    { $group: {
        _id : "$_id",
        attribute: {$addToSet:"$values.attribute"}                                   
      }
    },
    { $unwind: "$attribute" },
    { $group: { _id: "$attribute", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { "$match" : {count:3}},
)
```

and the addToSet seems faster than the group on a composite key.

Thank you very Anand, your help was very appreciated!